# Why show an audit review answer if my review filter excludes answers?

Tags: support, review-audits, filtering

I was performing some *First Posts* reviews on an SE site that has audit reviews enabled. And I had enabled the filter to limit it to Questions only (I wanted to skip all Answers to be reviewed). However, one of the posts to be reviewed was [this audit review](https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/986562), about an answer!

Why show an answer as audit review if my review filter excludes answers? That makes no sense to me (instead such audit review should have been about some question, not an answer) and smells like a bug. Or am I missing something?